# Moving images/links with CSS

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

I need help with this small little problem I am having with the site I am building. I have a list of images with links to different websites and everything looks fine for the most part but when I hover over the last one in the row the links below move for some strange reason. I can't figure out!

Imagine this what it looks like at first:

```
[img1] [img2] [img3]
[img4] [img5] [img6]
```

This is what happens when I hover over any of the images/links on the right side:

```
[img1] [img2] [img3]
              [img4]
[img5] [img6] [img7]
```

And this is my code:

```
.sites{
float:left;
width:215px;
background: #eee;
text-align:center;
margin: 0px 13px 15px 0px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
padding:10px;
}

.sites p{
margin:0px;
padding:10px;
font:bold;
}

.sites a{
border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
border-top: 5px solid #000;
display:block;
}

.sites a:hover{
border-bottom: #F90;
border-top: #f90;
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="main-content">    
<h1> Check out all our DEADicated sites: </h1>
<div class="sites">
    <a href="http://www.eyeem.com/TheDEADicated" target="_blank">
    <img src="images/sites/eye-em.jpg" width="215" height="150" alt="EyeEm"/></a>
    <p> EyeEm </p>
</div>
<div class="sites">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/DeadSaraArg" target="_blank">
    <img src="images/sites/fb-argentina.jpg" width="215" height="150" alt="Facebook    Argentina"/></a>
    <p> Facebook - Argentina </p>
</div>
<div class="sites">     
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/The-DEADicated-Canada/427270554005649?ref=hl" target="_blank">
    <img src="images/sites/fb-canada.jpg" width="215" height="150" alt="Facebook Canada"/></a>
    <p> Facebook - Canada </p>
</div>

<div class="sites">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/ThedeadicatedEgypt" target="_blank">
    <img src="images/sites/fb-egypt.jpg" width="215" height="150" alt="Facebook Egypt"/></a>
    <p> Facebook - Egypt </p>

</div>
<div class="sites">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/DeadSaraItaly?ref=hl" target="_blank">
    <img src="images/sites/fb-italy.jpg" width="215" height="150" alt="Facebook Italy"/></a>
    <p> Facebook - Italy </p>
</div>
<div class="sites">     
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/thedeadicatedmexico" target="_blank">
    <img src="images/sites/fb-mexico.jpg" width="215" height="150" alt="Facebook Mexico"/></a>
    <p> Facebook - Mexico </p>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="sites">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/DeadSaraTheDeadicatedUK" target="_blank">
    <img src="images/sites/fb-uk.jpg" width="215" height="150" alt="Facebook UK"/></a>
    <p> Facebook - UK </p>
</div>

</br><br><br>

<h2> To join TheDEADicated, click <a href="http://musichype.com/artists/dead-sara" target="_blank">HERE</a>! </h2>



</div>
```

I'm pretty new to web design. Help please?

Comment: Have you got the markup that you're using for the links as well?

Comment: Please share your HTML code in jsfiddle.

Comment: I have added my HTML code in the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without html I can't say for sure, but just from your css, your `.sites a:hover` rule should be setting `border-top-color: #F90; border-bottom-color: #F90;` rather than just border-top and border-bottom.

Comment: tim that fixed the problem! thank you so much.. i still don't understand tho why would that make the images move??